# Elasticsearch : Encountered a retryable error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have written a Logstash config file such that it reads the log messages a file and then transfer data to elasticsearch.

Location of the config file: pipe.conf

/etc/logstash/conf.d

pipe.conf has the following contents:

```
input
{

  file
  {
        path => "/var/log/elasticsearch/file.log"

        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        start_position => "beginning"

        type => "doc"
  }
}

output
{

      elasticsearch
     {

     hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
     action => "create"
     index => ["logs"]
     }


}
```

When Logstash runs, error occurs,

```
"[Ruby-0-Thread-10@[main]>worker3: :1] elasticsearch - Encountered a retryable error. Will Retry with exponential backoff  {:code=>400, :url=>"http://localhost:9200/_bulk"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Default action is create. so need to add action.
  `elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "logs"
  }`